# Java comparing 2d arrays to 2d arrays inside arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am having problems checking if the arrays inside one array are the same as my arrays in a list. This is the problem code, it does not seem to stop duplicates from being added. Arrays.equals() doesn't seem to work either:

```
if(!uniqueTiles.contains(playerPositions[i])) {
    uniqueTiles.add(playerPositions[i]);
}
```

Here is the entire method so far:

```
// gets the area in fishZone that the bot should walk to, based on the positions 
    // of clusters of players

    List<Player> players = getPlayers().getAll();



    int validPlayerCount = 0;

    // count valid players
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        if((players.get(i).getName() != myPlayer().getName()) && fishingZone.contains(players.get(i))) {
            validPlayerCount++;
        }
    }

    int[][] playerPositions = new int[validPlayerCount][2];
    List<int[]> uniqueTiles = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    // put the x and y coordinates of all nearby valid players into a 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < validPlayerCount; i++) {
            playerPositions[i][0] = players.get(i).getX();
            playerPositions[i][1] = players.get(i).getY();



            if(!uniqueTiles.contains(playerPositions[i])) {
                uniqueTiles.add(playerPositions[i]);
            }
    }
```

As you can see uniqueTiles is an arrayList because it needs a flexible size, and playerPositions is a 2d array.

Comment: oh just realized another problem with this, I get the number of valid players but then loop through the entire player's list...anyways that shouldn't change this issue with duplicates being added.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s if you don't want duplicates:

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements.

In Java, object comparison is made using the methods `equals` and `hashCode`. You can use third party libraries such as Apache Commons Lang's EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder to help you implementing those.

Look at the source code of `List.contains` if you're curious.

Comment: I tried using a set but that still seemed to allow duplicate arrays to be added

Comment: @joshfairbanks That should not happen. You've tried using HashSet class? The entire point of the Set interface is to not allow duplicates...

Comment: Set<int[]> uniqueTiles = new HashSet<int[]>(); // what I used

Comment: @joshfairbanks Duplicate detection is not automatic, even with a Set. You need to implement both equals and hashCode. If you don't, your program will compare the memory address of objects. If you have two array instances with the same values, their memory address will still be different and List.contains will return `false`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
TreeSet<Integer[]> set = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> Arrays.deepEquals(o1, o2) ? 0 : 1);
    set.add(new Integer[]{1, 2, 4});
    set.add(new Integer[]{1, 2, 4});
    set.add(new Integer[]{1, 2, 4});
    System.out.println(set);
```